# Obtain a variable from API, Illegal string offset

Tags: php

I want use true money payment on my website.
The source code is there : [class.truewallet.php](https://github.com/exzajung/class.truewallet.php)

in another file when i test the payment, i would like to obtain the variable "amount" which i need to continue my script.

the test in php is :

```js
$token = json_decode($wallet->GetToken(),true)['data']['accessToken']; 
echo $wallet->Topup($codeTrue,$token);
```

the result will be an array :

```
{
  "amount": "",
  "serviceFee": "",
  "cashcardPin": "",
  "createDate": "",
  "sourceFee": "",
  "totalAmount": "",
  "transactionId": "",
  "remainingBalance": ""
}
```

If the payment is done, i'll got values for each one.

I need to extract the amount value into a variable

When i do :

```js
 $amount = $token['amount'];
 echo $amount;
```

i have the following error :
"Warning: Illegal string offset 'amount' "

so i cant use my variable amount.

How can i do to extract the amount into a variable?

Comment: Check that the JSON string is what you expect it to be. The error message essentially says that you try an array access on a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the amount value from the $token variable, but the amount is part of the "Topup" result.

Try this:

```
$token = json_decode($wallet->GetToken(),true)['data']['accessToken']; 
$response = $wallet->Topup($codeTrue,$token);
$amount = $response['amount'];
echo $amount;
```

I ignore the response type (I don't know if it is an array, a class...), you could try to decode the response if it isn't an array.

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahmm, the $token is a string not the 'array' you posted above. That is the result of `$wallet->Topup()`.

So save the result of that function to a variable. Json decode it and then take the amount from there.

```
$token = json_decode($wallet->GetToken(),true)['data']['accessToken']; 
$response = $wallet->Topup($codeTrue,$token);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
$amount = $response['amount'];
echo $amount;
```

PS: if `$wallet->Topup()` isn't executed with success, 'amount' may, or may not be set, so maybe you will also need to check if the operation was successful.

Comment: i test your suggestion who is interesting. The error disappear. So I have tested again making a payment to get a value to amount. A new error pop up : Undefined index : amount

Answer (score 0):

here the solution working:

```js
$token = json_decode($wallet->GetToken(),true)['data']['accessToken'];
//echo $wallet->Topup($codeTrue,$token);
$response = $wallet->Topup($codeTrue,$token);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
        $amount = $response['amount'];
        echo $amount.'THB';
```

I miss to delete the 2nd row.
istaro and igs013 , you were right. Thank you.